# Can Sublime Text jump inside <li>foo</li> with a shortcut?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext2

I can't figure out a way to jump inside of  html brackets in Sublime Text 2. For example I would like to jump from * to $ in my sample below.

I've tried using ctrl+m and ctrl+shift+m , but they don't seem to be working. 
Currently I have to hit opt+leftArrow + leftArrow + leftArrow

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>$</li*>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I can think of is `Command+Shift+A` which will jump to `$` and select it. You can find it under Selection > Expand Selection to Tag